Can a simple neural network model(MLP) predict or fit the square root of x?
According to the description in the Can AI Predict What Will Happen? section of the article Can AI Solve Science? on stephenwolfram.com,

... there are "no model-less models": different activation functions lead to different predictions, and the form of the predictions seems to be a direct reflection of the form of the activation function.

So if I train a model as shown in the figure to calculate $\sqrt x$ (instead of $sin x$ as mentioned in the article), I will eventually get an expression like this to describe $\sqrt x$:

class SimpleNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleNN, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(1, 3)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(3, 3)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(3, 1)
        self.active_function = torch.relu
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.active_function(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.active_function(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)
        return x

However, I think the classical activation functions(e.g. $ReLU$) do not produce components like $x^n$, so this expression is very different from the Taylor series, and I am afraid it cannot predict or fit $\sqrt x$, unless the activation function contains the
power of $x$, just like using activation functions contains $sin$ or $cos$ component to fit $sinx$ itself in the article.
In addition, can an RNN predict or fit a non-periodic function such as $\sqrt x$?

Why would you want to use RNN for the typical regression task like that? There is no sequential data you need to follow that would imply using recurrences.
As of your first question, have you actually tried training your network? Simple NNs grasp elementary functions quite easily, given you’ve trained them well and correctly.
